# Creating an Excel VBA array with unassigned variables as entries

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to set up a workflow/UX where a CSV file is imported and each column of the imported file is assigned a "data type" using dropdowns at the top of each column. Once these data types are designated/assigned to each column, another macro populates a second sheet with the imported CSV data, where the location in the new sheet is dependent on the data type designated for each column of the imported data.

For example, if the first column of the imported data is of data type "DataA", the dropdown selection would be selected as such for this first column (from a total of 12 "data types" in the dropdown menu). This "DataA" data would then be populated in the second sheet in its fifth column.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim DataA As Integer, DataB As Integer, DataC As Integer, DataD As Integer, DataE As Integer, DataF As Integer, DataG As Integer, DataH As Integer, DataI As Integer, DataJ As Integer, DataK As Integer, DataL As Integer

    Dim ColArray(12) As Variant

    For p = 1 To LastColImport 'This is a previously-defined/assigned variable

        q = 1

        Do While q <= 12

        If ActiveSheet.DropDowns(p).Value = q Then

            ColArray(q) = p

            Exit Do

            Else

            q = q + 1

        End If

        Loop

    Next p
```

This populates the `ColArray` array with an integer entry if the data type is selected, or an empty entry if it has not been selected. The next step I want to do is assign each `ColArray` entry value to a named variable, so that I can call the `ColArray` entry values by data type name instead of having to remember or look up what data type each `ColArray` integer value refers to.

I can't find a built-in "dropdown list range name" recall function anywhere, so what I would like to do is the following:

```
Dim ColArrayNames(12) As Variant

ColArrayNames(1) = DataA 'These variables were defined in the previous code block
ColArrayNames(2) = DataB

...

ColArrayNames(12) = DataL


ColArrayNames = ColArray
```

I realize that in this specific case, it would probably be easier to just assign the data type variables directly to the ColArray values, instead of putting them into an array and then equating the array values. I feel like populating an array with unassigned variables could be useful in other cases as well. My attempts at using this method of assigning variables have failed.

After changing the last line of code to:

```
For i = 1 to 12

ColArrayNames(i) = ColArray(i)

Next i
```

The `ColArray` values don't get assigned to the data type variables. That being said, the `ColArrayNames` entries are assigned the correct values, so the issue seems to be the "last step" in assigning the ColArray values to the data type variables by way of the `ColArrayNames` array of unassigned variables.

If anyone has suggestions for how to approach this "general" problem of using arrays of unassigned variables to assign values to each array entry (while preserving the ability to call these values using the entries' "original" variable names), or if there's a more efficient way of approaching this spreadsheet function altogether, please let me know!

EDIT 1: As requested by John Coleman, I'll elaborate a bit more on what I'm trying to do here.

Once I have the imported column numbers assigned to a data type, I want to send the data to a second sheet with some code in a manner such as:

```
For i = 2 to LastRow 'The LastRow variable value will be found using a simple xlDown search process

Worksheets(2).Cells(1,i).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(DataA,i).Value
Worksheets(2).Cells(4,i).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(DataB,i).Value

Etc.

Next i
```

Again, I realize that I could just as easily use

```
Worksheets(2).Cells(1,i).Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(ColArrayNames(1),i).Value
```

and so on, but I feel like if what I'm asking about is possible, I might be able to use it in another situation (even if it's not the most ideal method for this example).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, perhaps you could explain a bit more. I suspect that a `dictionary` might help. This is not native VBA (it comes from VBScript) but is used by most VBA developers as a standard tool. See this: http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html . This would allow you to access information from a string (which is what I *think* you mean by `"original" variable names`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, John - when I have a bit of time I'll update the original post to include the "next step". Roughly, what I want to do is be able to populate the second sheet with some code like `For i = 2 to LastRow    Worksheets(2).Cells(1,j) = Worksheets(1).Cells(DataA,j)` and so on for each data type column. Since I know what the data type is supposed to be in the second sheet's column, but the first sheet is variable (dependent on the imported data). This way I can call the appropriate data type from the imported data using the data type variable instead of the ColArray place.

Comment: Okay I've updated the original post for you @JohnColeman , hopefully it makes more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

For as best as I understand your problem, it seems to come down to effectively (and efficiently) defining a data map between the original source data and the formatted output (in this case, cells on a second worksheet).

When confronted with the data typing part of the problem, I realized the ultimate "holder" of the destination data type is the object that holds it -- in this case its the worksheet cell, not the VBA variable or array. Your focus seems to be on the VBA code that transfers/copies the data from one worksheet to another (or to/from variant arrays). Your own choice in efficiency should be your guide here. If you want to use relatively general purpose code for multiple data types, my suggestion is to use a `Variant` value or array and after copied to the destination cell, set the format of the destination cell (which effectively "types" it for whatever later use necessary).

A dictionary may not even be necessary if the mapping table can be flexibly scanned to accommodate any number of data types, formats, or columns.

Comment: I think I'm using the term "data type" in a different way than you're interpreting it. I'm using "data type" in the context of "what the data is referring to" (e.g. "mass", "speed", "height"), and not what the code data type is (e.g. "integer", "long", "string"). Currently I have the sheet importing all data as "General" and handling them in the same way. The relevance of the data type to my output is where in the output sheet it is placed (the input is of non-standard column arrangement/order, the output is of standard column arrangement/order).

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at the dictionary usage yet, as it seems like it may be unnecessary for what I'm trying to do here (though I imagine it might be worth using in other situations).